# ffmpeg output in multiple files one after another

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, v4l2

I am using `ffmpeg` to read from the camera using `v4l2` and I need the output videos to be 1 min length.

Is it possible to make `ffmpeg` to output in files of fixed time length?

I tried using `-t 60` and restarting `ffmpeg` in a loop, but it loses a few frames on each restart.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks cover this?

Comment: Use the [segment](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer.